# Is there a way in windows 7 to search for file by time created?

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-search, file-search

Basically I would like to sort or search for files by time created, with the date as a wildcard.

IE search for files made after 6PM, but before 6AM.  I know it shows the time in "Date Created," but I have to search thousands of files created over years that were made after 6PM.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a Powershell solution using GetChildItem

```
Get-ChildItem -filter "*.*" -path "C:\path\to-you-files\" | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Hour -gt "18" -or $_.CreationTime.Hour -lt "6" }
```

where -gt is greater than 18:00 Hours
and -lt is less than 06:00 Hours

NB. If files are copied to directory or created and overwritten then you could replace CreationTime with LastWriteTime